How to make an exe from python script using pyinstaller which can be used to connect to DB2 using ibm_db module
I made a script to connect to DB2 using ibm_db python module. It works fine when ran through script but when I convert it to exe I get error as [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved. Reason code: "6". SQLCODE=-1042
Firstly while running import ibm_db in script, I encountered this error ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: The specified module could not be found.
I resolved this using os.add_dll_directory("C:\\..\\clidriver\\bin")
But when I made an exe using pyinstaller --onefile command, I'm getting this error [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved. Reason code: "6". SQLCODE=-1042
Can anyone pls give the detailed solution to resolve this

This is just one way to solve this problem, other ways are also possible.
This answer is specific to the following components , it might not work with other versions and will not work with other operating-systems, or might not work with additional packages that use ibm_db:

Microsoft-Windows x64
pip 24.1.1
pyinstaller 6.6.0 or higher.
ibm_db version 3.2.3 supplied as a wheel.
using clidriver as supplied by default with pip install ibm_db

Verify that your script runs correctly without pyinstaller (i.e. unbundled).
You need two things:

your python script needs startup code before importing ibm_db (see sample below) to locate clidriver regardless of whether your script is running unbundled, or bundled (with pyinstaller), so that the call to add_dll_directory works in either case.

the bundle has to contain the clidriver tree as an --add-binary in a subdirectory named clidriver.


Always bundle to a single-folder first (i.e. without using --onefile option) and get the single-folder method working before you attempt the --onefile option. This makes debugging easier. If your single-folder bundle does not work then your --onefile bundle will also not work. If the bundled clidriver throws SQL10007N, check whether adjusting the PATH (before running the single-folder bundle) to include the (single folder) clidriver\bin location, and adjusting the regional settings has any impact on behaviour. If so, you can adjust the PATH in your python script before running the import ibm_db also, using a similar technique to the sample below, but you must only append to the existing PATH not replace its value.
Sample code before import ibm_db is below:
import sys 
import os

# for ibm_db version 3.2.3 on microsoft-windows, works with/without pyinstaller.
# This is only valid if using clidriver (which comes by default with ibm_db wheels).
# For pyinstaller on ms-windows, use --add-binary /path/to/clidriver:./clidriver .
if ( sys.platform == "win32" ):
    site_packages=""
    clidriver_bin=""
    program_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __file__ ))
    
    for directory in sys.path:
        if 'clidriver' in directory and 'bin' in directory:
            clidriver_bin = directory
            break
        if 'site-packages' in directory:
            site_packages = directory
    
    if site_packages != "" and clidriver_bin == "": 
        clidriver = os.path.join(site_packages , "clidriver")
        clidriver_bin = os.path.join(clidriver, "bin") 
    
    if clidriver_bin == "" and site_packages == "": 
        clidriver_subdir = os.path.join( program_directory , "clidriver")
        if  os.path.isdir(clidriver_subdir):
            clidriver_bin = os.path.join(clidriver_subdir , "bin")
        else:
            print("Failed to find a bundled clidriver directory at: " + clidriver_subdir )
            sys.exit()

    if clidriver_bin != "" and os.path.isdir(clidriver_bin):
        os.add_dll_directory(clidriver_bin)
    else:
        print("Missing directory: " + clidriver_bin )
        sys.exit()

import ibm_db

If your python script is named myscript.py, and contains the above fragment, an example command line to bundle it to a single-folder is  (replace the c:\path\to\clidriver by your real site-packages location ):
pyinstaller -y --add-binary c:\path\to\site-packages\clidriver:./clidriver  myscript.py
If and only if that approach works, you can create an executable with:
pyinstaller -y --add-binary c:\path\to\site-packages\clidriver:./clidriver --onefile myscript.py

Hi, I tried this approach and could make an exe. Using pyinstaller "-y --add-binary c:\path\to\site-packages\clidriver:./clidriver  myscript.py", I get a clidriver folder in the dist dir, but the error persists saying, "[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved. Reason code: "6". SQLCODE=-1042" possibly beause some of the message codes which are present in a file (probably msg folder inside clidriver dir) could not be fetched. Do you have any clue how to resolve this ?
Also what is file in os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( file ))

works fine for me, cannot tell why it fails for you, as your question gives no facts about your environment, versions, components etc. The double_underscore before/after file is a reserved token for python look it up, it means the currently running script.  You also MUST verify first that the bundle works without the --onefile option, as it makes for easier debugging.

I'm using Windows 10 64 bit with python 3.9.19 and ibm_db 3.2.3. I tried without using the --onefile option.
Got this input on github page, not sure how to implement, "Add full path of your clidriver/lib and clidriver/lib/icc in system level environment variable LIB using os package before importing ibm_db"

Do not add facts in comments, instead edit your original question to add those facts.  Comments are not searchable. Debug with the single folder bundle only.
